# Passing string into function doesn't set variable name

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable:

```
var chart;
```

A function which creates the chart:

```
function setChart(variableName, chartContainer){

variableName = new CanvasJS.Chart(chartContainer, {**params**});

 variableName.render();

};
```

I call setChart

```
setChart(chart, "chartContainDiv");
```

If I call `chart.render();` later, it doesn't work.

How can I achieve this? / What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're misunderstanding how JavaScript works; you can't do it like that. If you want to refer to a variable by name the closest equivalent would be to create an object and refer to its properties by name.

Comment: That's quite an edit. In any case, the issue is the same--you're setting a variable that's local to the function. If you need more than one instance, use an object, like I already said. If you need a single instance, then just use the global.

Comment: You are confusing passing [by value and passing by reference](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass). When you pass `chart` to `setChart` you can't assign it a value because you did not pass its reference you passed its value (which is `undefined` in your example).

Comment: @DaveNewton I know, sorry, I'm having one of those days.

Comment: @AlexW ok, so if I want to do the above, so that I can create a few different charts using the setChart function how would I do it?

Comment: @OliverJ90 I posted an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function as a [factory](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#factorypatternjavascript) that returns a chart object, instead of passing it an empty variable. This uses the exact same concept, by creating an object and then returning that object, but it doesn't use a CanvasJS object for simplicity purposes:

```
function setChart(chartContainer) {
    var variableName = new String(chartContainer);
    return variableName.toUpperCase();
};

var chart = setChart("chartContainDiv");
var chart2 = setChart("blahBlah");
console.log(chart.toString());    // "CHARTCONTAINDIV"
console.log(chart2.toString());   // "BLAHBLAH"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8Lg4wqy/3/

Comment: awesome, thanks, I was pretty much there it turns out, works a charm now.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're passing a string into the function, you end up trying to assign this:

```
setVar("globalVar");
// In setVar...
"globalVar" = 5
```

which obviously doesn't work. Passing in just the variable name itself will **almost** work as expected:

```
setVar(globalVar);
// In setVar...
globalVar = 5
```

**HOWEVER**

Because of variable scope, inside the `setVar` function you have a **local** variable with the same name as the **global** one. Doing any assignation here will just set the **local** variable to 5, where the **global** variable will remain at whatever value it used to be.

```
var myVar = 1;
function setVar(globalVar) { globalVar = 5; alert(globalVar); }
setVar(myVar); // alerts 5
alert(myVar); // alerts 1
```

---

Interestingly, if you pass the string in then you're able to set it via array-access on the `window` object:

```
setVar("globalVar");
// In setVar...
window[variableName] = 5; // window["globalVar"] = 5;
```

but trying to do that by passing the variable itself in doesn't work...

```
setVar(globalVar);
// In setVar...
window[globalVar] = 5; // window["5"] = 5 // or whatever globalVar contains
```

---

The TLDR version of this is that this is the only way to do this **exactly** as you're trying to do in the OP (although there are other ways such as Ahmad's answer, where you set a specific variable without passing it):

```
var myVar = 1;
function setVar(varName) { window[varName] = 5; }
setVar('myVar');
```

Comment: Passing in the variable name won't work as expected, unless you don't expect globalVar to be set to 5 outside of the function.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was halfway through typing as you were discussing :P I've updated it to mention the scoping, as the window[string-var-name] still works.

Comment: Removed my original comment, as it is no longer true! :)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to be clear on the scopes of variables and global variables. In you example, there is no line where you set `globalVar` to 5. You only set a local variable for the function setVar called variableName to 5.

what you should do is:

```
var globalVar;

function setVar(){
  globalVar = 5;
};
```

now if you want to have a global variable or a set of global variables then you should have them in an object and then have a function that take that variable name and an optional value that you to assign.

```
    var globalVariables = {"globalvar1" : "", "globalvar2" : "", .... };
    function setGlobalVar(variableName, Value) {
       globalVariables[variableName] = value;
    }

setGlobalVar ('globalvar1', 5); // this would do it
```

Comment: `window` is an object and the variable is in the global scope, so you can reference them by array notation via `window[variableName]` rather than having to put them inside another container object

Comment: its always good practice to minimize adding to `window` to keep global namespace clean (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679634/is-setting-properties-on-the-window-object-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Definitely, but he's already told us that it's a global variable (line 1 of the OP) and unless you're scoping this inside something else which you haven't shown in your answer, you're just creating a global object yourself, called `window.globalVariables` :-)

Comment: i was not clear on the global variable if its on the window or on a function scope :) apparently he edited the question now