# Is there a way that treat javascript function with dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, python, function, variables, ecmascript-6

I want to use function in my javascript code in dynamic way like this code.

```js
const function1 = (param) => {
    return "AA" + param
}
const function2 = (param) => {
    return "BB" + param
}
const function3 = (param) => {
    return "CC" + param
}

for (let i=1; i < 4; i++) {
    // call function1, 2, 3 with i
}
```

And I saw a similar case in python like this.

```py
note1 = "note1"
note2 = "note2"
note3 = "note3"

for i in range(1, 4):
    print(vars()[f"note{i}"])
```

like this python case, Is there a way that treat javascript variable or function with dynamic name?

Comment: Make them properties of an object, so `myObj['1'] = param => {...}` then `myObj[i]()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

Any function that is created outside any function, in non-strict mode, goes to default `this` (window). So you can access it as `window[ propertyName ]`. However, its a bad practice to pollute to window object. Hence better option is to wrap these functions in a custom object and then use same syntax to access functions.

```
const function1 = (param) => {
    return "AA" + param
}
const function2 = (param) => {
    return "BB" + param
}
const function3 = (param) => {
    return "CC" + param
}


for (let i=1; i < 4; i++) {
    window[`function${i}`](i);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Is setting properties on the Window object considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679634/is-setting-properties-on-the-window-object-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Bleeding properties to window is a bad practice

Comment: Yeah, this definitely technically accomplishes the stated goal, but if it's possible to use a custom wrapper object instead of the window object, prefer that.

Comment: If we are defining the functions in any other context then we can use that one instead of `window`.

Comment: @Rajesh neulhan just asked for possibility, as it seems that all functions are in global context so you have this option only.

Comment: @Rajesh As per my understanding, you can create a new function using `Function` and that one will always create Function in global context.

Comment: @Rajesh, Ok, atleast you should change the answer score to zero.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for the edit, looks good.