# Passing Variable in two JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to use the same variable which I have passed in another javascript file?
For example, if in firstfile.js I declared `const temp = 4;`
can I access `temp` in secondfile.js?

Comment: Have a look at the ES6 syntax for module.exports &/or export default

Comment: No, what is it? I am new to coding; please tell me.

Comment: Yes @AmAn KumAr you can.   If you are using both file on same page.  sequence also matter , your first file must be on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In firstfile.js Export `temp`,

```js
module.exports = { temp };
```

Get `temp` in Secondfile.js

```js
const { temp } = require("pathOfFirstFile.js")
```

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to make a music player. For that, I need an array of objects to load the song, song name, artist name, and album. This music player will have 50-60 music or maybe more in the future. If I include the array of objects in my main js file, it will become very long, which I don't want. So I was searching if there is a way to separate my whole list of music from the main js file.
Here is the GitHub link of the project 
https://github.com/amankumar6/Epic-Player

Comment: @AmAnKumAr, you need support for commonjs; which is native in node.js but not in browsers, where you need a third party provider like requirejs, browserify ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using javascript in frontend you can use global window variable.

But be warn to not use reserved variable name, so you can prefix your variable.

```js
// file1.js
window.myapp_temp = 4
```

```js
// file2.js
console.log(myapp_temp)
```

keep in mind that using global variable is consider as a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679634/is-setting-properties-on-the-window-object-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the following is not recommended, as it is a bad practice. Global variables that are implicitly read can create problems. **The `import` `export` patterns recommended in other answers are a better practice, as you have more explicit knowledge of where variables are coming from.**

**Only try out the following if you are curious to know about how browsers read script tags from top to bottom:**

If you are using html script tags, you may have script files (the order matters):

```html
<script src="firstFile.js"> </script>
<script src="secondFile.js"> </script>
```

As long as `const temp = 4;` is globally defined in `firstFile.js`, `secondFile.js` will have access to `temp`.

If you flipped the order:

```html
<script src="secondFile.js"> </script>
<script src="firstFile.js"> </script>
```

`secondFile.js` will not have access to `firstFile.js`.

Comment: But this technique of using globals is currently regarded as a **bad practice**. See answers below about ES Modules.

Answer (score 1):

The current best practice for the client-side is to use the ES6 modules. They separate their variables from each other, but you can export/import variables that are accessible to both files.

```html
<script type="module" src="secondfile.js">
```

```js
//firstfile.js
export const temp = 4
console.log('firstfile', temp) //4
```

```js
//secondfile.js
import {temp} from './firstfile.js'
console.log('secondfile', temp) //4
```

If you have to support some old browsers (see on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/es6-module)), you can still transcompile this code using something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

---

This solution also works in Node.js, however, you'll have to use the `.mjs` file extension or set `"type": "module"` in `package.json` (and the `--experimental-modules` flag if you're using version <14.0).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as they are both imported or declared in a single page.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Both are imported on the same page

Comment: both are on the same file or initialize on same page, for example they are both present in sample.html, but first make sure that the script containing initialization of variable is initialized first before the second one.